# How to know if a Time-Based Trigger has been deleted?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

```
function triggerdelete() {
  var indextrigger = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < indextrigger.length; i++) {
    if (indextrigger[i].getHandlerFunction() == 'responsechange') {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(indextrigger[i])
    }
  }
}
```

I have this code above. I've used `var triggerhandler = ScriptApp.newTrigger("responsechange").timeBased().after(60000).create().getHandlerFunction();` to get the handler function. It returns me **responechange** as the name of the HandlerFunction which I am not sure if it is right or wrong.

However, how do I know if my time-based trigger is being deleted after each run of the script? Right now, I have getting the error of "too many triggers in the script."

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can see all of the triggers for your projects by going to https://script.google.com/home/triggers.

Comment: @ross - This includes time-based trigger that is programmatically created? 
I tried the above, but doesn't seem to remove any trigger from my trigger page though.

Comment: Yes, all triggers are displayed there. Sounds like your `if` statement is not quite correct.

Comment: How is it not correct if I may know? I did include a console.log in that if loop, the console.log didn't show, so I assume it got deleted actually? After a few tries, with the same code, it worked. The triggers on my dashboard started to disappear after my 1 minute trigger. Guess it had to do with the single inverted commas. I had it changed to double it didn't work, and when I tried single, it worked.